# Find the differential equation for a family of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is stated as follows:

> Find the ordinary differential equation for the family of circumferences with radius equal to $1$ and whose center is in the circumference 
>   $$x^2+y^2=25$$

Any ideas? I got so far as to determine that $h^2+k^2 = 25$ so that the circumference's equation is defined as $(x-h)^2+(y-\sqrt{25-h^2})^2=1$ form there I'm not sure what I should do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "family of circumferences"? Do you mean family of circles?

Comment: I mean all functions of the form (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2 in this case, I'm looking for the ones where r is 1 and h and k are the coordinates of a point in the one in the problem definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had an ODE which, when solved, gave you a circle in the family of circles with radius 1 with center distance 5 from the origin. In addition, assume that it is 1st order.

Note that given any point distance between 4 and 6 from the origin, there are 2 circles in your family that go through it; this means that, given a fixed $x$ and $y$ in your ODE, there must be 2 solutions for $y'$. This suggests a quadratic ODE in $y'$.

Thus, to figure out the answer, pick an arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the plane; find the equations of the circles in your family that intersect $(x_0, y_0)$; find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(x_0, y_0)$ for each of those circles, giving two values $r_0(x_0, y_0)$ and $r_1(x_0, y_0)$ (or 1 value $r_0 = r_1$ if you have a degeneracy); and construct the quadratic $(y' - r_0)(y' - r_1) = 0$ which will be your desired ODE.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very clever!